# writing header into csv using php

Tags: php, csv

i have a requirement where i am logging each page visit and activities into csv log file. how can i write so that the header should be written for the first time only not every time.

```
fputcsv($fh1, array(date,id1,page,id2,request,ip));     
fputcsv($fh1, array($date,$mid,$page,$aid,$request,$ip));
```

The first array should be written once only for a particular date log file. Please Suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to kick yourself when you see this ...

```
if (!file_exists('log.csv'))
{
    // Make the file & Write the header
}
// Write the log entry.
```

Comment: Haha. yeah m kicking :) Thanks Mark.

Comment: No problem mate, it happens to me all of the time. [Rubber Ducky Programming](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html) helps with that.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are trying to arrange the record with header when you download CSV. If YES then please have a look on this example below, where I am showing it in small example which works in Drupal-

```
<?php

function getUsersDetails(){
    $csv_output = '';
    $all_users_entry = db_query("SELECT * FROM users");
    while($users = db_fetch_object($all_users_entry)){//suppose these fname,lname etc are column name of your table.
        $fname = $users->fname;
        $lname = $users->lname;
        $date = $users->joining_date;
        $role = $users->role;
        $location = $users->location;
        $csv_output .= "\"".$fname."\"".","."\"".$lname ."\"".","."\"".$date."\"".","."\"".$role."\"".","."\"".$location."\""."\r";
    }
    return $csv_output;
}

function download_details(){
    $csv_output = '';
    $csv_output .= "First Name,Last name,Member Since,Role,Place\n";
    $csv_output .= getUsersDetails();
    header('Content-type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Usera_Details.csv"');
    print $csv_output;
    exit;
}
?>
```

Now you can call this function download_details() from any place and you will have users table details in the downloaded CSV

Comment: No Rajeev this was not the case. i got the solution. Thanks